# Get TabItem Header from dynamic populated tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a tabcontrol that is populated from an observablecollection. Based on the observablecollection the tabitems headers gets set and datagrid in the tabitem gets populated. What I am trying to do is get the tabitem header and set it in a textblock. I was able to get the tabcontrol name and set it to a textblock text but not the header from the selected tabitem.

```
<TabControl  Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}" Height="Auto" Background="Transparent" x:Name="TabsName" >
                    <TabControl.Resources>
                        <localHelper:HeaderAppendConverter x:Key="HeaderAppedConvrter"/>
                    </TabControl.Resources>
                    <TabControl.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding HeaderText}"  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

                    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Name="Tabsitems">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="725" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1600" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                 <dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="NameGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" >
                                    <dxgcore:GridControl.Columns>

                                        <dxg:GridColumn Name="Month1" FieldName="Month01"  Visible="True" AllowEditing="False" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" CellStyle="{StaticResource NumberCellStyle}">
                                            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                                                <dxe:TextEditSettings HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                                            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                                            <dxg:GridColumn.Header>
                                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=SelectedItem.Header, Converter={StaticResource HeaderAppendConverter}, ConverterParameter='01'}" />
                                            </dxg:GridColumn.Header>

                                        </dxg:GridColumn>
                                          </dxg:GridColumn>
                                    </dxgcore:GridControl.Columns>
                                    <dxgcore:GridControl.View>
                                        <dxgcore:TableView x:Name="NameGridView" 
                                       AllowEditing="False" 
                                       AllowBestFit="True" 
                                       AllowMoving="True" 
                                       AllowColumnFiltering="True"
                                       IsColumnMenuEnabled="True"
                                       ShowGroupPanel="False"
                                       ShowAutoFilterRow="True"
                                       AutoWidth="False" 
                                       NavigationStyle="Cell"
                                       VerticalScrollbarVisibility="Visible"
                                       HorizontalScrollbarVisibility="Visible"
                                       RowStyle="{StaticResource customRowStyle}" >
                                        </dxgcore:TableView>
                                    </dxgcore:GridControl.View>
                                </dxg:GridControl>

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                </TabControl>


public class WorkSpace : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string headerText;
    public string HeaderText { get { return headerText; } set { headerText = value; OnPropertyChanged("HeaderText"); } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return HeaderText;
    }

    private List<Data> data;
    public List<Data> Data { get { return data; } set { data = value; OnPropertyChanged("Data"); } }
```

This line

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=Name}" />
```

sets the tabcontrol name to the textblock How can I change that to get the selected tabitem header text

Comment: Could you show me the `TextBlock place in xaml code?

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer the xaml textblock is in the original post below "This line" that line renders the tabcontrol name

Comment: Please show me how do you populate TabItems in Code behind?

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer Its an Observablecollection that contains class workspace, Workspace class contains a property HeaderText that I set a value to and a List<Data> which is another class but both of those are in workspace. List<Data> populates the grid and HeaderText goes to TabItem

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer what I am really trying to do, is I have a gridcontrol in the <DataTemplate x:Name="Tabsitems"> I am trying to change the gridcolumn headers for each column. Part of the value is in tabHeader wondering if this is even the right way

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer I tried the code that you posted below before its not going to work

Comment: What i got: that you want to be the column header of a Datagrid a TabItem that have Header="Tab 01" the column header becomes "Tab 01 Col 01" ?? so the column header = tabHeader + colheader ?

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer yes thats exactly what I want not sure if what I posted is the correct way to go about it

Comment: okay, what about the colum-header suffix is fixed for each column? or changeable?

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer yes so I have the Header for a column specific 01 and trung to append tab header to 01 again not sure if the above is best route to completing this

Comment: okay you can do this, i will type the answer.

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer Thanks but I dont think the using , Path=SelectedItem.Header, works to get the header name

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer I might need to add I am using DevExpress for the grid, its not working for me because I tried SelectedItemHeader

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer By the way is this the right way of doing this? Is there a more professional way of doing something like this

Comment: i think you have a Property Header in the TabItem Model?

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer can you direct me to that because I dont see the property Header

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer unless you mean the observablecollection HeaderText then yes

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer can you post your full solution

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer Thank You so much!! I'll see if I can integrate this in

Answer (score 0):

Add the flowing Converter to your Project:

```
public class HeaderAppendConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}{1}",value, parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Then add to your TabControl Container Resource the StaticResource:

```
  <local:HeaderAppendConverter x:Key="HeaderAppedConvrter"/>
```

Finally Update the TextBlock ;

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=SelectedItem.Header, Converter={StaticResource HeaderAppendConverter}, ConverterParameter=columnSuffix}" />
```

in the ConverterParameter you can pass your custom string

the full solution looks like:

the solution struct is:
[image: Solution Struct]

the Main window XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="Twest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Twest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:HeaderAppendConverter x:Key="HeaderAppendConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TabControl  Grid.Row="1"  Height="Auto" Background="Transparent" x:Name="TabControlMainName">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding HeaderText}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="Tabsitems">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="725" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1600" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=SelectedItem.Header, Converter={StaticResource HeaderAppendConverter}, ConverterParameter= columnSuffix}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

The MainWindow Code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Twest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<TabItem> tabs = new List<TabItem>();
        tabs.Add(new TabItem() { Name = "tab1", Header = "TAB 01" });
        tabs.Add(new TabItem() { Name = "tab2", Header = "TAB 02" });
        TabControlMainName.ItemsSource = tabs;
    }
}
```

}